# Get geolocation source

Tags: c++, geolocation

I am using [Location API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd464636%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the current location.
According to msdn, the location source could be GPS, Wifi Triangulation,IP, etc.

When I get a location, how can i tell what is the location's source? if it came form a GPS device or the location is based on availability of cell tower and/or WiFi access points.

I saw that in the locationreport you can [get the sensor id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317620%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). can I use this id to understand where the location came form?

Comment: I'm fairly confident that you won't be able to get that at all (at least not directly from the Location API - it's perhaps possible to dig out that the sensor ID corresponds to as a device in the device manager - but that probably requires admin rights on the machine, so won't be universally available). May I ask why you care?

Comment: @MatsPetersson perhapsI can use setupDi calls to find the device with this guid. do you know if the Guid corresponds to the device instance id? regarding why I care - I have an API that I need to implement and this is part of the API.

Comment: So, someone has specified an API for you to implement, and you are trying to use an existing API to find the information, where the information is not directly present. And no, I have no idea what the GUID is - nor how you'd convert the GUID to a hardware device.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to implement this part in a wy that is not the most accurate but it is enough in my case. I use the error radius to tell if the location came from a GPS or based on the availability of cell tower and/or WiFi access points. of course a bad GPS can give me a huge error radius, but in my case this is enough.